# self destruct eks cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, lifecycle, amazon-eks

we have a aws sandbox account for multiple users. I want to create a terraform/terragrunt project to create a aws EKS cluster and workers (which I have the code for).

Most of all, I want to code it in the terraform code that cluster to be destroyed automatically at the end of the day to avoid unnecessary costs.

I already coded a EKS cluster with workers and some applications.

Need lifecycle rules to destroy the clusters daily.

Comment: if you can use cron or lambda to schedule terraform apply and terraform destroy